# How to get file path from different sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in VBA. I have two sheets i.e. sheet1 has path of input Directory and Output directory.
On sheet2 i am started to code. i wants to read data from multiple xls files that are are stores in a folder . this folder path is specified in sheet1. i wants to copy all files headers from all xls files to sheet3 in a column.
my code is working well but i have given file path directly but i wants to get it from other sheet. Please help me. Below is my code and i have attched sheet1.[image: Sheet1 Data]

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim search_result As Range   'range search result
    Dim blank_cell As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Path = "D:\Testing\Data\Input\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
'--------------------------------------------
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    'MySheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
    'Set sh = MySheet()
   'Variable = ActiveSheet.Name
  ' Sheets(Variable).Range("A1:D1").Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet2").Column(B2).Select.Activate.Paste
   ' Sheets("Sheet2").Active
    'Columns("B2").Select
  Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
  Variable = ActiveSheet.Name
  wbk.Sheets(Variable).Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy

 Workbooks("Tool.xlsm").Activate
' Workbooks("DFT Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

  'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Columns("E").Select
  ' Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste

 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(3).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

' Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    wbk.Close savechanges:=False
    Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Path = Cells(2,2).value
```

This takes the Value of Cell B2 and stores it in the Path variable.
Another possibility:

```
Filename = Dir(Cells(2,2).value & "*.xls")
```

Comment: Application.Workbooks("Your_Workbook").Worksheets("Your_Sheet").Cells(2, 2)

Comment: Thanks for answer ....now the code working well. But the problem is when first file is opned and copy data to sheet2 successfully. but the opened file is not closed automatically its giving pop up like "Privacy warning: This document contains macros, ActivX controls, XML expansions pack information ......." then i need to click on yes then it goes for loop. How to avoid this

Comment: First google link ;)
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/519071-how-remove-privacy-warning.html